# How to print with a printer the contents of a React component without displaying it in the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Something like this I need, only when the user clicks on "Print it" the component mounts and the printing process begins.

Unfortunately, I haven't found anything that would work this way, and I don't want to mount dozens of components and then make display: hidden because of performance reasons.

```
import { useReactToPrint } from "react-to-print";
import Print from "./Print";

// Pseudo code
const handleClick = useReactToPrint({
  content: () => <Print id={id} />,
});

return (
  <>
    <button onClick={handleClick}> Print It </button>
  </>
);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to view precisely. Do you want to see what HTML output would be created?

Comment: @OFRBG They're using [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print) and they want to print the component without displaying it in the page.

Comment: @caTS Exactly..

Comment: I very much doubt it is feasible. The whole point of mounting the DOM nodes in the iframe is to use the window `.print` method. If you don't mount, the browser won't have anything to print. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print